# magento edit account information in sales tab

Tags: magento, email

Often times customers place an order and have a typo error in their email address.
When I edit the email address in the customer account, it doesn't change the email address associated with the order.

I can go into the database and edit the email address, but what i would really like is to be able to edit the "Account information" in the sales order just like I'm able to edit the shipping address.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful when defining the concept of *customer email address* because up to three different ones may exist depending on whether you refer to:

- The customer account (whose email can be found at `customer_entity.email`)
- The order shipping address (useful for contacting purposes during delivery and available at `sales_flat_order_address.email`)
- The payment contact information (ditto at `sales_flat_quote_address.email`)

Customers state most of the time a single contact information for all three different processes above, but exceptions to this rule do occur very often (i.e. gifts to friends, deliveries to holidays addresses,  different payment methods for business orders, and so on).

I say three assuming you haven't modified and/or installed magento/some plugin to better accommodate your operations.

Comment: Thanks!
I was more looking for help on being able to have a edit button in the sales order tab from where we can edit the email address, just like you can edit the shipping info.